# DBMS_SCHEDULING Repeat Interval - Half Hourly, 9-5, Mon-Fri

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

I'm trying to work out if I can put together a repeat interval to apply to a Schedule that runs every half an hour between 9-5 on Monday to Friday.

I have this so far but am struggling to limit the time to within 9-5

```
FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; BYHOUR=9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17;BYMINUTE= 30;
```

If I run this, it will execute correctly during the 9-5 period; however, it will also execute every 30 minutes past every hour **before** 9 and **after** 5. I need to to only begin running >= 09:00 and <=17:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that you're close - replace

```
BYMINUTE= 30
```

with

```
BYMINUTE= 0,30
```